# How i can fix no model telegram with pyinstaller?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZz1x.jpg)
How i can fixed it

The code works fine from within Pycharm, but when converting it into an executable file, this message appears to me when running

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.